# Laravel REST API and frontend

Tags: laravel, rest

I created a project in Laravel, small database and added REST API in laravel to connect mobile app with database. What should I use to get data from database in web application? Using laravel models is easy but is that a good way to create another controllers to handle forms etc instead using rest api controllers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel also support for Restful API in own way.
for this

- you create your controller in Api folder: `php artisan make:controller Api/TestController`
- define your routes in `routes/api.php` :

  ```
  Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], function (){
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/test'], function () {
      Route::get('/', 'TestController@list);
      Route::get('/single', 'TestController@single');
    });
  });
  ```
- create a resource collection for data that is an array of collection

  `php artisan make:resource Api/Collections TestCollection` this command create a collection in folder `app/Http/Resources/Api/Collections` 
  open in and change `toArray($request)` function and add a function `with($request)` like following code :

  ```
  public function toArray($request)
  {
    return $this->collection->map(function ($item){
      return [
          'id' => $item->id, // $item is instance of Test model
          'name' => $item->name,
          'description' => $item->description,
      ];
    });

  }

  public function with($request) // optional : this method return with of response 
   {
     return [
      'status' => true
     ];
   }
  ```
- so go to TestController and create a method for get all tests:

  ```
  public function list()
  {
     $tests = Test::all(); // your Test Model
     return new TestCollection($test); // TestCollection you created above
  }
  ```

this is return a json object that contains array of tests.

- for get a single test :
  `php artisan make:resource Api/Resources TestResource`

  then go to TestResource in `app/Http/Resources/Api/Collections` and change code like following:

  ```
  public function toArray($request)
  {
   return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'name' => $this->name, // $this is instance of Test model
      'description' => $this->description,
      'body' => $this->body,
      'diff_name' => $this->name_in_table  // you can change the name differ from name in model instance 
   ];
  }
  ```

so go to TestController and create a method for single test

```
public function single(Request $request)
{
    $test = Test::findOrFail($request->id);
    return new TestResource($test);
}
```

this a summary of Rest API in laravel. Hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

With laravel, you can reuse your api endpoints by taking advantage of the [`CreateFreshApiToken` middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).

Then you will only need to create new controllers and methods to display views. All of the CRUD stuff can be reused.